# xsl replace match ':' but not ': '

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an xml file which i am processing via xsl into a csv file. It's working amazingly well except.
The source xml contains a node whose value is a delimited string - the delimiter is a colon. 
The sections in the delimited string may contain a colon
I need to replace the delimiter with a \

ie my xml looks like this:

```
<docnode>
  <group>
    <parent>
      <child>value1a:value2:value3 part1: part2</child>
      <other>some other stuff I don't care about</other>
    </parent>
  <group>
  </group>
    <parent>
      <child>value1b:value2:value3 part1: part2</child>
      <other>some other stuff I don't care about</other>
    </parent>
  </group>
</docnode>
```

my xsl currently has:

```
<xsl:for-each select="group"><xsl:value-of select="translate(parent/child,':','\')"/></xsl:for-each>
```

this outputs

```
value1a\value2\value3 part1\ part2
value1b\value2\value3 part1\ part2
```

I need:

```
value1a\value2\value3 part1: part2
value1b\value2\value3 part1: part2
```

I know it's nuts, but I can't control the formats.

I'm thinking I should be able to use a regex :[\S] which will match a colon that does not have a space after it.e

I can't find anything about regex:translate (only regex:replace)
eg:

When I try either of those options, the xsl gives me nothing

Help??!!

Comment: Which XSLT processor are you using?

Comment: https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=21714

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using an XSLT 1.0 processor, with no extension functions, you will have to do something like:

```
<xsl:template match="/docnode">
    <xsl:for-each select="group">
        <xsl:call-template name="replace">
            <xsl:with-param name="string" select="parent/child"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="replace">
    <xsl:param name="string"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains($string, ':')">
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($string, ':')"/>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="starts-with(substring-after($string, ':'), ' ')">:</xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>\</xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
            <xsl:call-template name="replace">
                <xsl:with-param name="string" select="substring-after($string, ':')"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$string"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thats awesome, I really like they way you did that.  
When I run the xslt over my file I get only 1 record returned, not two. 
`<?xml version="1.0"?>  
value1a\value2\value3 part1: part2`

Any thoughts?

Comment: @David I believe there is an error in your example input. After the first `</parent>`,  you have `<group> </group>` instead of  `</group> <group>`. So there is only one group, and it contains an empty subgroup. Compare http://xsltransform.net/jz1PuQ5 against http://xsltransform.net/jz1PuQ5/1

Answer (score 0):

Initially I thought about *negative lookahead*:

```
<xsl:value-of select="replace(., ':(?!\\ )', '\\')"/>
```

but it seems that XSLT does not support this feature.

Instead use:

```
<xsl:value-of select="replace(., ':([^\\ ])', '\\$1')"/>
```

It means:

- find a `:`,
- followed by something other than a space `[^\\ ]`
- capture this group `(...)`,
- replace this with:

  - a backslash `\\`,
  - and the captured group `$1`.

Note that backslash chars in regex patterns must be doubled.

I tested this solution with an online XSLT verifier, using Saxon engine and XSLT version 2.0.

The whole template is:

```
<xsl:template match="child">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:value-of select="replace(., ':([^\\ ])', '\\$1')"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: For "followed by something other than a space `[^\\ ]`" I can't see what the doubled backslash is doing there. That means "something other than space or backslash". Surely you just want `[^ ]`.

Comment: Michael, you are right. The quotation of the space is not needed.